# Kohana 3.3 Model::factory() Class Not Found

Tags: php, kohana

So I am aware of the implementation of the PSR-0 standard in Kohana 3.3 . However, there must be something I am not understanding as I am getting a class not found error for the following code:

```
$model = Model::factory('MyModel');
```

the model definition is located at:

```
classes/Model/MyModel.php
```

How is it that my class is not being found exactly?

Actual Code:

Model located at `classes/Model/VoiceTalent.php`

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

    class VoiceTalent
    {
         //methods and fields
    }
```

Controller Code:

```
$talent = Model::factory('VoiceTalent');
```

Exact Error Message:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Model_VoiceTalent' not found
SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Model.php [ 26 ]
```

Comment: That looks like it should work. An easy way to debug is to add some dumps into the autoloader and see what file it's trying to load.

Comment: I have to agree with zombor that the file should be loaded and that, if you are having a problem, it is probably not do to with actually loading the file but with the content in the file itself.

Comment: It is dying in the factory method of the model. Let me recheck all my code, if it indeed not an autoloader issue.

Comment: @zombor edited with actual code. Am I crazy? I will go start dumping some stuff in the autoloader as you suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class is badly named.

You have:

```
class VoiceTalent
```

Should be:

```
class Model_VoiceTalent
```

as you have to include all folders it is contained within (separated by `_`) in the class name. In this case you just need to add `Model_` prefix. You can read more about [class naming convention in Kohana's docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/conventions#class-names-and-file-location).

Comment: And this is how I got my username.

Comment: By that logic we all should be having that nickname ;) Don't worry, we've all been there.